# Using sed command for a specific line

Tags: linux, bash, script, sed

I want to change a cell in file when my desired state exists. Example:

File:

```
id311    vmName1    state0
id312    vmName2    state0
id313    vmName3    state0
```

I will type a script and this script changes the state column of just one row. So if I type `sed -i 's/state0/state1/g'` all `state0`'s be `state1`. I want to change state of only one row like:

File:

```
id311    vmName1    state0
id312    vmName2    state1
id313    vmName3    state0
```

How can I use the `sed` command for a special line with use id?
note: id's are unique.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add the line number before: `sed '<line number>s/<search pattern>/<replacement string>/`.

```
$ sed '1s/state0/XXXX/' file
id311    vmName1    XXXX
id312    vmName2    state0
id313    vmName3    state0
```

Since you want to edit in place, say:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/state0/XXXX/' file
```

Note I use `.bak` after the `-i` flag. This will perform the change in `file` itself but also will create a `file.bak` backup file with the current content of `file` before the change.

---

For a variable line number use the variable normally, as well as double quotes to have it expanded:

```
sed -i.bak "${lineNumber}s/state0/XXXX/" file
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change the file I think so. I want to change line in the file.

Comment: @A.Guven just place the `-i` as your attempt shows.

Comment: Well, how can I use this with a variable like $lineNumber?

Comment: @A.Guven see update.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I use the `sed` command for a special line with use id? note: id's are unique.

Since `id`s are unique, it make sense to use the first field as a key:

```
sed -i '/id312/s/state0/state1/' file
```

---

You could want to create a command, and pass the id number and the file as parameters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -i "/id$1/s/state0/state1/" $2
```

invoking it like this:

```
./sed.sh 312 file
```

**Note:** Always be careful with the `-i` switch: test first without it.

Comment: thanks. but i cannot use parameter with a script. there is a bug on my platform i think so. but anyway your solution is true. thanks again.

Comment: i get the line number by using id with "cat -n" for now.

Comment: @A.Guven You can skip the intermediate passage about the line number and use the id as in the first example.

Comment: yeah right. sorry, my brain does not working right now :)